# c# plugin system question

Tags: c#, plugins, interface, types

so I implemented a really simple plugin system.

i have the following Assemblies:

```
MainApp
IPlugin
PluginApp
```

Both `MainApp` and `PluginApp` conatin a reference to the `IPlugin`. Now, in `MainApp` I scan a plugins folder and search for things that implement the `IPlugin` interface.

However, it is not working because both `MainApp` and `PluginApp` reference their own copy of `IPlugin.dll` so they are not recognized as a match when using `Type.IsAssignableFrom()`!

help?

Comment: Could you explain what you mean (or why) they "reference their own copy of IPlugin.dll"?

Comment: How come you have different `IPlugin.dll`s?

Comment: IPlugin.dll contains the interface for plugins must implement. So everyone who creates a plugin must include this in their project. Then, inside my MainApp, I must also include this. If I delete the IPlugin.dll from the plugins build, it will work fine. However, I cannot control what DLL plugin creators include - so I don't think this is a good solution (Like, if someone include the dll my app should not fall apart).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try putting your code that defines the plugin into a satellite dll assembly.  That way both your main code and the plugins reference the same types.

---

If the plugin can maintain it's own dll instead of using the same dll as the application you will run into versioning issues.  How will your main app handle calling plugins that don't implement the same interface?

When we did this in our own software we had to resort to reflection method calls instead of casting to the interface.  It wasn't elegant.

---

What about adding the assemblies dll into the plugin directory.  They have to reference the dll when they create their application, but force them to use the main assemblies version of the dll when the plugin is actually run?

Comment: Errr...I used the wrong term.  Satellite assembly is actually used to house resources.  I meant an assembly that can host the interface code but that would not be hard coded into the main assembly.

Comment: I am actually already doing that (IPlugin.dll). How can I ensure that plugin creators will use my dll? And if someone happened to include their own dll into their project, how can I prevent my app from falling apart?

Comment: When you compile the main app you set the specific version property to true on the reference to your iplugin dll.  Your app won't start without the correct version.  The plugin dll projects should not have the specific version property set to true.